Changing the date field in biblatex with apa style
I am using biblatex to print my bibliography and am citing books where I need to specify the original date the book was published (same for other sources).
When the bibliography compiles, it puts the year field from my .bib file in parentheses after the author and, if existing, the original date in parentheses after the publisher with a string like "originally published YEAR" (mine is german, but the principle is the same).
What I want is for the original year to be displayed in the parentheses after the author and the year the book was published after the publisher at the end.
If there is no origdate field, I want it to go the standard way and just put the year after the author and nothing at the end.
I have succeed to replace the origdate field with the year value (the field is called "date" as far as I understand it), but the other way around does not work, no matter how I put the code.
Here is what I tried:
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Replacing year with origyear if origyear exists.
\renewbibmacro*{date}{
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {\printtext[parens]{\thefield{origyear}}}
    {\printtext[parens]{\thefield{year}}}}

% Replacing the origyear with the date field.
\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{
    \iflistundef{origyear}
        {\printdate}
        {}
}


\addbibresource{Literature.bib}


What should happen is:
Baudrillard, J. (1987). Amerika. Matthes & Seitz. 2004.
What actually happens is:
Baudrillard, J. (2004). Amerika. Matthes & Seitz. 2004.
I experimented around a bit, trying to change the value of the date macro (or the place where year is displayed), but it never changes.
I am a bit lost.
If there are easier ways of circumventing this issue I am of course open to suggestions.
It just has to be formatted exactly the way above.

Okay, I think I found the answer, at least the code now does what I want it to do:
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}


\DeclareLabeldate{\field{origyear}\field{year}}

% Replacing the origyear with the date field.
\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printdate}
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {\setunit{\addspace} \thefield{year}}
    {\setunit{\addspace} \thefield{origyear}}
}

\addbibresource{Literature.bib}

What this does is change date's content to the value of the field origdate in case the field exists.
Then the Macro that later generates origdate is filled with the content of year, but only if the field actually has a value.
Then I had to change the cite command to not display both year and origyear.
Now the output is what I wanted:
John Doe. 2023. Booktitle. Publisher. (1923)
if the book has an original date or
John Doe. 2023. Booktitle. Publisher.
In case there is only a value for year.

Actually, with the apa style, you might only need to focus on the labelyear+extradate and origyear bibmacros. They both work for the bibliography. The first one concerns what you'll get just after the author's name. The second one, by default, concerns, if given, origdate and the apa style introduces it with a specific string and prints within parentheses.
What you need to do is redefine the labelyear+extradate bibmacro, to immediately impose a test to check if origdate is given and then establish the consequences. As for the origyear bibmacro, you also need to set everything up with the same kind of test, but, amongst the consequences, you need to print the year of the current edition cited. In short, you have to use these two bibmacros, which by default each have their own function, and invert these two functions.
\renewbibmacro*{labelyear+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\iffieldundef{labelyear}%
            {}%
            {\printtext[apadate]{\printlabeldateextra}}}%
        {\printtext[apadate]{\printorigdate}}}

\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{origyear}}%
                and
                not test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
                and
                not test {\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origyear}}}%
        {\newunit\newblock%
            \printtext[apadate]{\printdate}%
            \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}%
        {}}

Once you've done this, I suggest that you also adjust the citation bibmacros. This allows the year that appears with the \cite, \citeyear and similar commands to always remain the same as the one that appears in the bibliography, after the author's name. Here too, you have first to impose a test, in order to check if origdate` is given, and establish the appropriate consequences.
\renewbibmacro*{cite:plabelyear+extradate}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \clearfield{labelmonth}%
    \clearfield{labelday}%
    \clearfield{labelendmonth}%
    \clearfield{labelendday}%
    \clearfield{labelyeardivision}%
    \clearfield{labelendyeardivision}%
    \iffieldsequal{labelyear}{labelendyear}%
        {\clearfield{labelendyear}}%
        {}%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\printlabeldateextra}%
        {\printorigdateextra}}}

Here you are back a MWE with these three bibmacros later.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa,annotation=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{labelyear+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\iffieldundef{labelyear}%
            {}%
            {\printtext[apadate]{\printlabeldateextra}}}%
        {\printtext[apadate]{\printorigdate}}}

\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{origyear}}%
                and
                not test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
                and
                not test {\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origyear}}}%
        {\newunit\newblock%
            \printtext[apadate]{\printdate}%
            \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}%
        {}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:plabelyear+extradate}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \clearfield{labelmonth}%
    \clearfield{labelday}%
    \clearfield{labelendmonth}%
    \clearfield{labelendday}%
    \clearfield{labelyeardivision}%
    \clearfield{labelendyeardivision}%
    \iffieldsequal{labelyear}{labelendyear}%
        {\clearfield{labelendyear}}%
        {}%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {\printlabeldateextra}%
        {\printorigdateextra}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\cite{kullback:reprint}

\cite{kullback}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

Try with these bibmacros: I hope they actually answer what you requested.
